# $(#id).className jQuery not working in IE9

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-9

i am trying to get className of a  tag using its ID. These TR tags are generated using ASP response.write, and the jquery is written inside a function which will be called on button click and this button is a TD inside the same row which pass rowid as parameter. I am not sure what is going wrong as it works fine with IE7,IE8 and IE9 compatibility mode.

Please help me to get though this.

Following is are my codes

JS:

```
function rowvalue(id){
    var namecls = $("#tabrow" + id).className;
}
```

ASP:

```vb
response.write "<TR id="tabrow" & rid & " class=""Row" & (Cn) & """>"
response.write "<TD>"
response.write "<BUTTON onclick=""Javascript:rowvalue(" & ID & ")"">Edit</BUTTON></TD>"
response.write "</TD>"
response.write "</Tr>"
```

Comment: Please provide some code of how you are actually doing that currently.

Comment: `$("#id").className` shouldn't work on any browser configuration if using jQuery. Also, what do you need the id for if the button is already inside it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
$('#id').attr("class")
```

That should work. It fetches the value from the "class" attribute.

Possibly interesting, there are also some class-related functions that can come in handy: http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/class-attribute/

Comment: Glad I could help! A vote/accept of the answer would be greatly appreciated ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try `$(#id).attr('class')` instead - ?

Answer (score 1):

1. It's not jQuery related, className is a DOM attribute and [it works in IE9 PR3](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_html.html)
2. Use `$(#id).attr('class')`.

Answer (score 0):

```
function rowvalue(id){
    var namecls = document.getElementById("tabrow" + id).className;
}
```